# Spark Graphx Vertices with Multiple Attributes (Type Mismatch - Product with Serializable Error)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm using Spark 2.3.0 with graphx. I have a simple DF that resembles a menu structure, like so: [Menu Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIt0.png). When I create a graph with three vertex attributes (Int,String,String) using the following code to create the Vertex RDD, it works perfectly:

```
val menuVerticesRDD: RDD[(VertexId, (Int,String,String))] = menuVertexDF
.rdd
.map{row: Row => (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2))}
.map{x => (MurmurHash3.stringHash(x._1.toString).toLong, 
( x._1.asInstanceOf[Int], x._2.asInstanceOf[String], x._3.asInstanceOf[String] ))}
```

Then I try the exact same thing with four attributes (Int,String,String,String) using the following code:

```
val menuVerticesRDD: RDD[(VertexId, (Int,String,String,String))] = menuVertexDF
.rdd
.map{row: Row => (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3))}
.map{x => (MurmurHash3.stringHash(x._1.toString).toLong, (  x._1.asInstanceOf[Int], x._2.asInstanceOf[String], x._3.asInstanceOf[String], x._4.asInstanceOf[String] ))
```

... which then throws a type mismatch error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:153: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, (Int,     String, String, String))]
(which expands to)  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, String, String, String))]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Product with Serializable)]
(which expands to)  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Product with Serializable)]
```

**What I tried so far:**

- I checked the graphx api docs @ https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD, but it doesn't seem to me that there should be a problem with adding an infinite amount of attributes, as long as you wrap them in a tuple.
- I tried adding `Seq()`or `flatMap()` before the tuple with no success
- I tried finding examples of graphs online with more than three vertex attributes, but it seems there are not any
- I tried using SQL to exclude any Null values from the starting DF

So yeah, I've essentially reached the point where I feel like a complete brickhead. I have the feeling I'm overlooking something very simple here, but after playing around and researching for almost a day now any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please Include the Menu Structure image within your question.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let me as I do not have enough reputation. Please refer to  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIt0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are doing fine but missed to passed the default tuple. Initialize your graph in following manner.

```
val graph = Graph(menuVerticesRDD, menuEdgesRDD, (0, "NONE", "NONE", "NONE"))
```

The third param is "defaultVertexAttr" which should comply the datatype of vertex